# Checking if an item is in an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

I am checking whether an item is in a an array in C using a for loop to iterate through every item in the array and comparing it one by one with a user input.

```
int main()
{
    char birds[] =
    {
        [0] = "a",
        [1] = "b",
        [2] = "c",
        [3] = "d",
        [4] = "e",
        [5] = "f",
        [6] = "g",
        [7] = "h"
    };
    int birdfound;
    int i;
    printf("Enter bird:");
    scanf("%c", &birdfound);
    //printf("%c", birdfound);
    for(i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        //printf("Y");
        if(birdfound == birds[i]){
            printf("Bird in array, found at position %d\n", i);
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I know for a fact that the issue lies within branch logic, as for some reason it fails to compare the character input with any character from the array. Therefore, the output is nothing and the program simply ends.

Comment: You should have a look what your compiler is telling you, the online compiler tells you this: https://ideone.com/uyYSrk

Comment: This code isn't valid C and won't compile cleanly, so that's your problem.

Comment: You ever heard of [`strchr()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strrchr.3.html)?

Comment: `"a"`, with double quotes, is not a `char`, it is a `char *`. `'a'`, with simple quotes, is a `char`.

Comment: @mouviciel: `"a"` is a `/*readonly*/char[2]`; `'a'` is an `int`.

Answer (score 5):

You're assigning string literals to your `char`s. Try this instead:

```
char birds[] =
    {
        [0] = 'a',
        [1] = 'b',
        [2] = 'c',
        [3] = 'd',
        [4] = 'e',
        [5] = 'f',
        [6] = 'g',
        [7] = 'h'
    };
```

Also, `int birdfound` must be `char birdfound`, otherwise `scanf("%c", &birdfound);` is undefined behavior because you're telling it that it's a `char` when it really is an `int`.

---

In all likelyhood your intention is to use strings instead when all is said and done, which you could achieve this way:

```
char *birds[] = // note the "*"
    {
        [0] = "foo",
        [1] = "bar",
    };
```

Then you read it in like this:

```
char birdfound[20]; // space for 19 chars and the null terminator
scanf("%19s", &birdfound); // read up to 19 chars
```

And find it like this:

```
if (!strcmp(birdfound, birds[i])) {
    printf("Bird in array, found at position %d\n", i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already got the answer, however, there's another way of achieving the same without getting into the scenario which caused the problem.

Code is self-explanatory, with comments.

Reference: [man page for `strchr()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strchr)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)  // correct signature
{
    char *str = "abcdefgh";                   // define the string in which to search
    char check = -1;                          // to hold the user input
    if (scanf("%c", &check) != 1) {           // basic sanity check with scanf
        exit (-1);
    }

    char * res = strchr (str, check);          // check whether the input is preset or not

    if (!res) {                                // return null pointer, means not found
        printf("not Found!!");
    }
    else {                                     // not null, match found
        printf("Found %c\n", *res);
    }
    return 0;
}
```